# Returning when any Future in a list finishes

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

I have a coroutine that should perform a few tasks concurrently:

```
@gen.coroutine
def scrape_trackers(self):
    yield [self.scrape_tracker(tracker) for tracker in self.torrent.trackers]
```

Some trackers will never respond (or maybe respond in an hour), so my code never gets past this method, as Tornado is waiting for *all* of them to complete. How do I wait for only *one* to complete and keep trying the other ones in the background?

Something like:

```
yield WhenAnyComplete(map(self.scrape_tracker, self.torrent.trackers))
```

I was thinking of calling each of those methods with `IOLoop.add_callback()` and doing something when they finish, but I'm not entirely sure where to go from there:

```
for tracker in self.torrent.trackers:
    future = self.scrape_tracker(tracker)
    IOLoop.add_future(future, self.tracker_scraped)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A [channel](http://pythonhosted.org/async/api.html#module-async.channel)?

Comment: @minitech: Sounds about right. Twisted, Tornado, and Tulip don't seem to have anything similar, so I'll take a look at async if I can't come up with something.

Comment: Never mind, they have the same issue as far as I can tell. On the other hand, from [the documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine): *Coroutines may “return” by raising the special exception [`Return(value)`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Return).* Does that work?

Comment: @minitech: I can return from the coroutine, but I'd like to do that *only* when the first successful scrape happens. All of them should also concurrently, which is what causes problems. If they ran sequentially, I could do just that.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is returning a new `Future` and having the first successful function call give it a result:

```
def scrape_trackers(self):
    result = Future()

    for tracker in self.torrent.trackers:
        future = self.scrape_tracker(tracker)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda f: self.tracker_done(f, result))

    return result

def tracker_done(self, future, result_future):
    if future.exception():
        logging.warning('Tracker could not be scraped: %s', future.exception())
        return

    logging.info('Scraped tracker %s', future)

    if self.unconnected_peers:
        result_future.set_result(True)
```

Comment: If `set_result` is the way a future is supposed to return a value, then I don’t see how it could get any better than what you have here.

Answer (score 0):

The [yieldpoints](http://yieldpoints.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library has a `WaitAny` function.  It predates Tornado's use of `Futures`, though, so it's a little cumbersome to use now.  It might be best to look at the source for `yieldpoints.WaitAny` and `tornado.gen.YieldFuture` to make a hybrid of the two.

Alternately, you could reorganize your code such that `WaitAny` is no longer necessary.  Instead of one coroutine that peels off results as they are finished, just start a new coroutine for each task and join them all at the end:

```
@gen.coroutine
def process_tracker(self, tracker): 
    result = yield self.scrape_tracker(tracker)
    # Do whatever you'd do after WaitAny here.  All the process_tracker
    # calls can proceed in parallel as their results are ready.

@gen.coroutine
def process_all_trackers(self, trackers):
    yield [self.process_tracker(t) for t in trackers]
```